# Is it worth upgrading to 28mm tyres from 25 for a 250 mile ride?

Tags: tire, speed, road, comfort, tyre-width

Next month I'm embarking on a 250 mile ride over one day - I've done plenty of training and I'm ready. Currently my bike has 25mm tyres and some of the 100 - 175mile training rides I've done have proved by the end fairly uncomfortable.

I'm wondering what real world difference in terms of watts having 28's on instead of 25's would make? Obviously over 250 miles we won't be going very fast, perhaps averaging 16mph or so.

The route is fairly flat (St. Ives Cambridgeshire -> Newcastle (in the UK)). So I guess weight isn't a huge issue.

Is there a calculator or something out there that can help me decide?

Comment: If you can maintain 16mph you'll be looking at a journey time of 15.5 hours,  I'd personally have a rest break every 3 hours and forget about the slightly wider tires.

Comment: Wider tyres will let you run a lower pressure which, in theory, will be more comfortable. Personally I have moved from 25mm to 28mm in the last few months and the difference is small, but noticeable. You're going to be on the bike a long time and towards the end it's going to be a chore, comfort probably a good idea.

Comment: not sure if a calculator is possible, but there's always [bicyclerollingresistance.com](https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/specials/conti-gp4000s-ii-23-25-28) if you want to become obsessed over individual watts :) (danger, madness etc etc...)

Comment: Impossible to answer as its largely down to the road surface.  In many cases the 28 may actually be quicker

Comment: Comfort is the main factor in my pondering of this purchase, and there will be frequent short (10-15 min) stops (I'd be surprised if anyone can do 250 miles without stopping?!) If there's not really any noticeable diff in comfort then it's not worth the bother I guess

Comment: personally, i'd switch to a 28 mm for a 25-mile ride

Comment: You may want to research some previous questions on tire sizing. Unless you change just the size, but keep to the same brand and model of tire you can't tell for sure if there is an appreciable difference in size. One brand of 28mm may be the same size as a 25mm from your brand.

Comment: I wouldn't go smaller that 38 mm; save the high heels for the "presentation and poise" segment of the Miss Bicycle pageant.

Answer (score 11):

If you're going to change anything before the big event, change it now and allow time for any problems to arise, then be sorted out before the event.

Generally, a 28mm tyre is said to give lower rolling resistance over a 25mm and has been [tested](https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/specials/conti-gp4000s-ii-23-25-28), though using a 28mm at the same pressure as the 25mm could spoil some of the comfort advantages. The numbers tell us that you could run a 28mm tyre at 20 psi lower than a 25 with very little performance difference.

More significant might be saving a few more watts with tyre choice to a different model in 28mm, but beware increased cost and (possible) lower puncture resistance.

So, if there's little difference in performance, or even an improvement and a 28mm proves to be more comfortable for you (higher volume, lower pressure) then you're looking at a win-win. Just watch out for frame and fork, brake, clearance for the larger tyres. Another reason to test now, not in a month's time.

Up to you if you want to spend the money, but I would try it for yourself rather than focus too much on what you can find written on the internet, some of it may be written by advertising experts for a start.

Comment: The linked test doesn't mention that, but at same pressure a wider tire will be harsher. At usable pressure there is almost no difference in rolling resistance, but wider tire will have more margin before the rim hits the road.

Comment: @ojs good point, I'll edit something in

Comment: Despite potential rolling resistance savings (not getting into this debate), wider tyres will almost always come with an aero penalty as well. Some modern aero wheels are wide enough to negate this, but most will be optimised for 25mm or narrower.

Comment: *If you're going to change anything before the big event, change it now and allow time for any problems to arise, then be sorted out before the event.*  And to find out if the larger tires actually are better for long-distance rides. They may not be for some reason.

Comment: @Carbonsideup - I have considered this. Due to the massive distance involved we're unlikely to be going very fast therefore the aero penalty will likely be much lower than one would generally think. I think?!

Comment: @JohnHunt For a 400km ride, the key point is puncture resistance anyways. Depending on road conditions, a non-puncture proof tire may force you to patch tubes several times, while puncture resistant tires only have a very slight chance to fail you. (I'd *estimate* that chance somewhere in the ballpark of about 4%, depending on brand and road conditions.) I mean, what good is the fastest tire when there's no air in it?

Comment: I have bought some Shwalbe One 28mm.. not exactly a puncture proof tyre, but should be good all-rounder offering that extra comfort I was after. I'll post results here of whether or not I thought it was worth doing afterwards (in about a month)